# Displaying php output

Tags: php

I have a PHP function that, when a user submits a form, should display file names which contain the string form the form, but it does not work.

In the first page load nothing appears (blank page), and in the second page load all data in the column named `fileName` appears.

Why is this happening?

```
<?php
    require('PDO_DB_connect.php');
    $search = $_POST['search_value'];

    $sql_query = "SELECT `fileName` FROM `upload_files` WHERE `fileName` LIKE    :keyword;"; 
    $query = dbConnect()->prepare($sql_query);
    $query->bindValue(':keyword','%'.$search.'%');
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->fetchAll();

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        echo "<li>".$row['fileName']."</li>";
    }

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because on initial load, `$_POST` is usually unpopulated

Comment: you need an `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST") { ... search code here ... }` guardian.

Comment: Major cleanup of problem summary; reduced newlines in the code

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your parameter as string, like so:

```
$query->bindValue(':keyword','%'.$search.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
```